# how to hide all excluding file type

Tags: python, file, operating-system, hide, glob

I'm trying to hide all my files excluding [.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7i9G.png).

**Below hides**: files, exe

Does not hide: folders

**I want**:
Hide folders, files

Does not hide: .exe

```
import os, shutil
import ctypes
folder = 'C:\\Users\\TestingAZ1'
for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(file_path, 2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I cannot use `-onefile` due to large size for each exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using glob to separate, then hide.

```
import glob

files_extensions = ('.exe')

def globby():
    for file in files_extensions:
        _globby = (glob.glob('C:\\Users\\TestingAZ1' + file, recursive=False))
        print(_globby)

globby()
```

Comment: Can you show example say my folder was: C:\\Users\\TestingAZ1.  Atm I'm not seeing any changes .

Comment: Alright so nothing changes in the directory when I run that.